# Received unregistered task of type KeyError on production

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, celery, supervisord

I have **Celery** periodic tasks which doing some job and send email to me after that.

It works perfect on local machine but fails on the **DO Ubuntu server** with error:
`Received unregistered task of type KeyError('periodic_tasks.send_email_task',)`.

My *periodic_tasks.py* file looks like this:

```
app = Celery('periodic_tasks', broker='')
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task(soft_time_limit=2000, max_retries=2)
def send_email_task(task_db_id):
    db = DBMethods()
    client_listings = dw.generate_client_listings(db)
    current_task = db.get_scheduled_task_data(task_db_id)
    query = current_task.get('task_params').get('query')
    days_stay = current_task.get('task_params').get('days_stay')
    proxy = current_task.get('task_params').get('proxy')
    adults_count = int(current_task.get('task_params').get('adults_count'))
    pets_count = int(current_task.get('task_params').get('pets_count'))
    to_email = current_task.get('task_params').get('to_email')
    cc_email = current_task.get('task_params').get('cc_email')
    additional_text = current_task.get('task_params').get('additional_text')

    task_id = str(send_email_task.request.id),
    task_data = {
        "task_id": task_id,
        "task_name": "send_email_task",
        "task_args": [client_listings, query, proxy, days_stay, adults_count, pets_count,
                                 to_email, cc_email, additional_text],
        "task_start_at": datetime.now(),
        "task_status": 0
    }
    db.start_scheduled_task(task_data)

    try:
        logger.info(email_worker_new(db, client_listings, query, proxy, days_stay, adults_count, pets_count,
                                 to_email, cc_email, additional_text))

        db.finish_scheduled_task(task_id, 1, datetime.now(), 'success')
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        db.finish_scheduled_task(task_id, 9, datetime.now(), 'timeout')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "send-email-001-task": {
        "task": "periodic_tasks.send_email_task",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="0", hour="*/2"),
        "args": ('email_001', )
    },
}
```

Run celery with command - `celery -A periodic_tasks worker -B  --loglevel=info` in **supervisord**

Please, help me. What am I doing wrong on production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical "problem".

-You need to re-deploy the latest code to all the machines running Celery workers, so they have new tasks registered.

You need a good deployment strategy. The simplest thing you can do is to build a Python wheel with all your Celery tasks packaged, and do `pip install -U your-project` on all machines that run Celery. Naturally, you also need to restart Celery as well...

Once your new code is there, and your Celery workers are up and running, you can check whether your new task is registered by running `celery -A periodic_tasks inspect registered`. You should see your new task(s) in this list.

Comment: You mean restart Celery workers? I've restarted Celery, restarted the server - nothing

Comment: "just" restarting will not help. You need the latest code there too, so Celery worker picks all the new tasks.